# WCF service credentials in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core-2.0

I've tried to implement simple username and password validation for my WCF service. My client is a web client in asp.net-core-2.0.

When I'm making a call from my client my System.Private.ServiceModel throws the following exception:

> "TransportSecurityBindingElement.BuildChannelFactoryCore is not supported."

Does that mean client credentials is not yet supported in asp.net-core 2.0? If so is there any way to work around this or do I have to work in a different framework?

Bear in mind this is my first time implementing validation on a service in WCF so I'm looking for clear instructions or examples.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the message feature in security is not yet supported in asp.net core-2.0.

You can see a full overview of what is supported [here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md)

Comment: so, what did you do in order to overcome this?

Comment: I wouldn't say we overcame it. We sent tokens over messages and authenticated the call that way. This was only for a school project though.

Answer (score 2):

Update dependencies in visual studio

[image]

or in *.csproj (vs code)

[image]

- **System.ServiceModel.Duplex v4.4.0** to **v4.7.0**
- **System.ServiceModel.Http v4.4.0** to **v4.7.0**
- **System.ServiceModel.NetTcp v4.4.0** to **v4.7.0**
- **System.ServiceModel.Security v4.4.0** to **v4.7.0**

Works in .net core 2.2 and .net core 3.1